# VBA warning when cells selected are not equal to 5 and contiguous

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

My Vb macro does the following:
I select 5 contiguous cells, run my macro and I get 5 static random numbers between 1 and 50;
It works perfectly;
I need a warning when the selected cells are not contiguous and not equal to 5.
The select cells must be 5 and contiguous.
Have no idea how and where shall I put the warning.
Thanks!

```
Sub loto()
    from = 1
    until = 50
 Selection.ClearContents
    For Each cell In Selection.Cells
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection) = (until - from + 1) Then Exit For
        Do
            rndNumber = Int((until - from + 1) * Rnd() + from)
        Loop Until Selection.Cells.Find(rndNumber, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing
        cell.Value = rndNumber
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your direct question:

```
If Selection.Areas.Count > 1 Or Selection.Cells.Count <> 5 Then
```

More completely, we can clean up your code a bit to remove extraneous lines and add some extra checks. For instance, your will error out if the user selects a shape and then runs the code.

```
Sub loto()

    'Declarations
    Const minValue As Integer = 1
    Const maxValue As Integer = 50
    Const cellCount As Integer = 5
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim errorMessage As String
    errorMessage = "You must select " & cellCount & " contiguous cells!"

    'Check that the selection is a range of cells and not some object
    On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = Selection
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox errorMessage, vbExclamation, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Check that five contiguous cells are selected
    If rng.Areas.Count > 1 Or rng.Cells.Count <> cellCount Then
        MsgBox errorMessage, vbExclamation, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Loop through each and add values
    rng.ClearContents
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        Do
            cell.Value = Int((maxValue - minValue + 1) * Rnd() + minValue)
        Loop Until WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, cell.Value) = 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It works perfectly!
Just have to read it and read it again to understand the details
Fantastic result!
Thanks a lot.

Comment: The routine is very consistent, I really like it!

Comment: I would probably move the magic number 5 to a "const" in the declarations section to further generalize the code.

Comment: @Emanuel I expanded the `IF` statements out instead of crunching them on a single line as I am prone to do for simply statements. I hope that makes it a little easier to follow. If there are bits you don't understand, try searching for an explanation yourself and, if you can't find it, come back here or post a new question.

Comment: @Yorik I have integrated your fine suggestion.

Comment: It has been a while since I used VBA. Is using a previously declared constant in the definition of a second constant legal now? Was that VB6? Am I mad?

Comment: Oh, you changed that error text to a string

Comment: Much easier to understand it (never thought about the practical side of defining message-errors as declarations). Now trying to understand WorksheetFunction.CountIf in VBA context… almost there. It remains me using a COUNTIF function in a validation data context (using a formula) i.e. to avoid entering duplicate values in range A1:A100: =COUNTIF($A$1:$A$100,A1)=1

Comment: @Emanuel In this context, it forces it to loop until the random value is unique within the range. Your original code did the same thing with the `.Find() Is Nothing` operation. Mine is different because I set the cell value and then checked that it was unique while yours found a unique number first and then set it as the cell value.